# Need help regarding regular expression to parse this string

Tags: php, regex, expression

I do not know regex well. And need help in fetching some data from a string, if any one can help, please.
When i am pasting the string over here it format the HTML so pls check pastebin link.

Okay, so what i need is every field data from this string, i.e. "Pickup From:", "Deliver To:", "Special Instruction:", etc. And the format will remain same, i.e every time break will be there, etc. Only inner data will change.

Like for example: Pickup From: Washington, DC, USA

So i need answer "Washington, DC, USA" only.

[Check Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/KJAMfbzN)

Can anyone help? I am using php.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need regular expressions here. Use `explode()`.

```
$string = 'Pickup From: Washington, DC, USA';
$ar = explode(': ', $string);
if (count($ar) == 2) { # Want to check to make sure it's not empty!
   echo $ar[1]; # Echoes "Washington, DC, USA"
}
```

Comment: Why was there a downvote on this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want all the fields:

```
$in = '<a href="example.com/edit"> Edit Your Delivery Details  </a>Pickup From: Washington, DC, USA<br>Deliver To: WDG Architecture, Connecticut Avenue Northwest, Washington, D.C., DC<br>Special Instruction: Yes, order fast<br>Person Name: sdf<br>Person Contact: dfsdf<br>Person Email: sdfsdasd@asd.asd<br>Pickup Day: Today<br>Pickup Time: ASAP<br><br>';

$lines = explode("<br>", $in);
$matches = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strstr($line, ":")) {
        $matches[] = preg_split("/\s*:\s*/", $line, 2);
    }
}
print_r($matches);
```

Gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  Edit Your Delivery Details  
Pickup From
            [1] => Washington, DC, USA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Deliver To
            [1] => WDG Architecture, Connecticut Avenue Northwest, Washington, D.C., DC
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Special Instruction
            [1] => Yes, order fast
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Person Name
            [1] => sdf
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Person Contact
            [1] => dfsdf
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Person Email
            [1] => sdfsdasd@asd.asd
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Pickup Day
            [1] => Today
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Pickup Time
            [1] => ASAP
        )

)
```

As you can see it's not quite perfect yet, but it gets you there.

Use a strpos to find the `</a>` and trim. If you have more *noise* like that you will need to trim it as well.

---

To the person who downvoted: can you please explain your downvote? Did I miss something?

Comment: Who downvote it? It works

Comment: The only problem is here is that, in first array i got
            [0] =>  Edit Your Delivery Details  
Pickup From: Washington, DC
        )

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

```
((?<=(Pickup\sFrom:)).*|(?<=(Deliver\sTo:)).*|(?<=(Special\sInstruction:)).*)
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be decided without regular expressions:

```
$test = "Pickup From: Washington, DC, USA";
$position = strrpos($test, ':');
$string = $test;
if ($position !== false)
    $string = substr($test, $position+1);
else
    $string = $test;

echo $string;
```

With reqular expression:

```
$test = "Pickup From: Washington, DC, USA";
if (preg_match('/: ([^,]+, [A-Z]{2}, [A-Z]{3})$/', $test, $m) !== false)
    $string = $m[1];
else
    $string = $test;

print_r($string);
```